# Adding a logo to a title in Pandoc's PDF output

Tags: titles, pandoc

I'm using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to convert Markdown to PDF via LaTeX. I'm very happy with the result, particularly now I've discovered Pandoc's support for [YAML document metadata](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139205/78754) with which you can make [substantial customisations](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) to output.

However, I have been asked to include our company logo (available as PNG or SVG) above the document title.

I suspect this can be achieved by modifying the Pandoc template.

Alternatively, perhaps an included `.tex` or `.latex` document could adjusts the way the title is displayed / laid out (I'm not sure if LaTeX supports this kind of "overriding"?) like this:

```
----
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: some-file-with-title-customisations.tex
      before_body: or-in-here.tex
      after_body: or-maybe-here.tex
----
```

I'm not sure what I should customise in the template (or in a file that I include), and how I should customise it, though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am no pandoc user, but I think we need more information what you're actually doing there.

Answer (score 7):

For the documentation of a recent customer project I used the following (modified) section to replace the respective lines of the default Pandoc template (which itself can be printed with the `pandoc -D latex` command):

```
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
  \null
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \includegraphics[width=3em]{red_corner.png}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushleft}\leavevmode
    \titlefont
    {\LARGE \@title\par}%
    \authorfont
    \vskip 1cm
    %{\normalsize \@author\par}%
    {\large \@author\par}%
    \normalfont
    \vskip 2cm
    {\normalsize \@date\par}%
  \end{flushleft}%
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
      \includegraphics[width=3em]{green_corner.png}
  \end{flushright}%
  \null
  \cleardoublepage
  }
\makeatother
```

It includes two small graphics on the title page.

This should serve you as an idea trigger how you can achieve what you imagine for your own title page.

***Caveats***

Above snippet additionally uses customizations `authorfont` and `titlefont` which are defined in the same template, earlier, as:

```
\definecolor{lhgray}{HTML}{494949}
\newfontfamily\titlefont{Source Sans Pro Bold}
\newfontfamily\authorfont[Color={lhgray}]{Source Sans Pro}
```

***Howto***

So just create your new Pandoc template by following these steps:

1. Run `pandoc -D latex > my-pandoc-latex.template`
2. Edit the file `my-pandoc-latex.template` according to your needs, using above snippets as inspiration.
3. Produce your output by running `pandoc --template my-pandoc-latex.template ...`

Comment: Thank you – I'll give this a try when recreating the documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-logo.html):

```
title: |
  ![](logo.jpg){width=1in}  
  Adding a Logo to LaTeX Title
```

Comment: The cookbook is updated - it shows a better way to do it now using the `titling` package.