# Fallback characters with combofont for teletype font?

Tags: fonts, luatex

I'm trying to find a solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177985/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf-fixing-missing-character-warnings ; and for that, I found:

- [Inserting _any_ unicode character in Latex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512396/inserting-any-unicode-character-in-latex-document)
- [Adding headers and footers using Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139139/adding-headers-and-footers-using-pandoc)

... and I *almost* got there with `combofont`; here is an MWE, with the headers output from `pandoc`:

`tester.tex`:

(EDIT: look in the history to see the original output from `pandoc` - I've cut off most of the preamble stuff, and it seems the below MWE reproduces the same problem):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{combofont}
\setupcombofont{multiscript-regular}
{
  {file:lmroman10-regular.otf:\combodefaultfeat} at #1pt, % have this in C:/Windows/Fonts/lmroman10-regular.otf ; C:/bin/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
  {file:DejaVuSerif.ttf} at #1pt % have this in C:/Windows/Fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf ; C:/msys64/mingw64/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSerif.ttf ;
}
{
   {},
   fallback
}
\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{multiscript}{}
\DeclareFontShape {TU}{multiscript}{m}{n} {<->combo*multiscript-regular}{}
%\renewcommand\ttdefault{multiscript} % TEX.SE 514940
\AtBeginDocument{\fontfamily{multiscript}\selectfont} % have to do it this way; if the ...\selectfont is just in the header, then \begin{document} resets it, so then we'd have to write the ...\selectfont in the body of the document explicitly, which we'd rather not do

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

Here is a test of a glyph that otherwise trips up *latex: ┌

%\begin{verbatim}
%Here is a test of the same glyph inside verbatim: ┌ ...
%\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this:

```
$ lualatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode tester.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
 restricted system commands enabled.

luaotfload | loaders : eval: found tfmdata for "luaotfload<1>", injecting.

$ grep 'Missing character' tester.log
```

... and the PDF result is:

[image: pdf-ok]

So, for normal/roman/upright text, the glyph is successfully replaced, and there are no 'Missing character' messages in log.

---

Now, if you uncomment the `{verbatim}` snippet in the `tester.tex`, the compilation result is:

```
$ lualatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode tester.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
 restricted system commands enabled.

luaotfload | loaders : eval: found tfmdata for "luaotfload<1>", injecting.

$ grep 'Missing character' tester.log
Missing character: There is no ┌ (U+250C) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
```

... and the resulting PDF is:

[image: pdf-bad]

So, the character did get replaced in normal text and font - but did not get replaced in the `{verbatim}` environment text, where teletype font is used (and a corresponding "Missing character" is output in log).

---

My question is: how can I set up `combofont`, so I can provide a character fallback, for everywhere a teletype font is used (`verbatim` and `lstlisting` environments, etc)?

(as a note, I was originally interested to provide fallback glyphs only for the teletype text/font; the only reason I provide a fallback for the normal text/font in the above MWE, is because that is the only thing I could get working so far - so at least it is a good starting point).

---

EDIT: Found a work-around here: [Define fallback font for missing glyphs in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514940/define-fallback-font-for-missing-glyphs-in-lualatex/514984#514984) - seemingly, all I was missing was a `\renewcommand\ttdefault{multiscript}` after the `\DeclareFontShape` command. This does work, and produces this in PDF:

[image: pdf-better]

... however, then this uses `DejaVuSerif.ttf` as fallback for the teletype font - so I do not get a teletype/mono font shown at all; but what I'd like is to use `DejaVuSerif.ttf` as fallback for normal/upright/roman text - and use `DejaVuSansMono.ttf` as fallback for teletype text; how can I do that?

Comment: This is not a MWE. You are mixing in xetex code, hyperref , secnumdepth, list settings and more. Make your code readable by removing all this unrelated stuff.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer - I've edited the example, hope it is more readable now, otherwise let me know.

Comment: I have no time now, but try with a fallback: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/2388